# How to define a link in part of an i18n Thymeleaf / Spring message?

Tags: spring, hyperlink, internationalization, thymeleaf

Using Spring / Thymeleaf i18n, I'd like to create a HTML paragraph message like "Click here", in which there is a link only for the word "here". What is the best way to do this?

The way I tried doesn't look nice and also results in a like break:

In messages.properties file:

```
error.generic.click=Click
error.generic.here=here
```

And in the HTML file:

```
        <p th:text="#{error.generic.click}"></p><p><a th:text="#{error.generic.here}" th:href="@{/contact}"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Answer**

Your way seems okay to me. If you just want to fix the newline issue go ahead with the following one:

```
<p>
    <span th:text="#{error.generic.click}"></span>
    <a th:text="#{error.generic.here}" th:href="@{/contact}"></a>
</p>
```

The `span` will make "Click" stay on the same line as "here". However i'd just go for a link that say "Click here" instead of just "here".

For example in german you could say "Hier klicken". "Hier" would mean "here" and "klicken" would mean "click". The Problem is that the meaning for the words changed but the position didn't. You would end up with a link saying "klicken" instead of "Hier".

**Not recommented**

There is another approach, but it has some drawbacks. You could use:

```
<p th:utext="#{error.generic}"></p>
```

with the following messages.properties:

```
error.generic=Click <a href="/contact">here</a>
```

The drawback on this one is that you **can't** use th:href anymore. I would not recomment this way. However this can be helpfull when using no `th:*` and just plain html tags. So i wanted to mention it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer